# How to store large amount of not much changing data in reactjs fetched from api?

Tags: reactjs

I need to fetch data of all the countries and display it on a map using reactjs.Do i need to store the data in client side as well? I have cached the response in api server. Where do i store the data in client side if yes? Is local storage good? The data does not change that frequently either. Fetching from api everytime doesnot seem to be a good idea.

Comment: Yes, you need to store data in client side and localStorage is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, best option is to do it with `localStorage` ,

Answer (score 2):

> IndexedDB is a way for you to persistently store data inside a user's
> browser. Because it lets you create web applications with rich query
> abilities regardless of network availability, these applications can
> work both online and offline. IndexedDB is useful for applications
> that store a large amount of data (for example, a catalog of DVDs in a
> lending library) and applications that don't need persistent internet
> connectivity to work (for example, mail clients, to-do lists, and
> notepads).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Terminology

Comment: I will have a look at it. Thank you!